# Getting error while sending email with Laravel 5.6 in controller action

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting error `Undefined property: stdClass::$email`
[image: error]

The code in my controller action:

```
...
use App\Mail\WelcomeMail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

public function approve($id){
    $mail = DB::select('select pic_email from vendors where id = :id', ['id' => $id]);
    $user = DB::select('select roc_no from vendors where id = :id', ['id' => $id]);
    Mail::to($mail)->send(new WelcomeMail($user));
    return redirect('/account/pending')->with('success', 'Account approved!');
}
```

In app\Mail\WelcomeMail.php:

```
class WelcomeMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.welcome');
    }
}
```

I write the code following the tutorial from https://www.5balloons.info/send-email-registration-laravel-authentication/

I use Mailtrap. All the credentials/configurations in .env are correct as the Laravel built-in password reset functionality is working. So what's wrong with my code?

Update: I'm going to trace the error and possibly from the controller action, which is `$mail = DB::select('select pic_email from vendors where id = :id', ['id' => $id]);` 
I'm using SQL the value is returned. Then I tried using tinker the value `$mail` is returned as array. I think it is the problem which cause the failure to get `$mail`.

How to correct this? Using `extract()` also gives nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The `DB::select` function returns an array of objects. `DB::selectOne` will return a single object, indexed by column name.

You can also combine your two queries into a single query, and then access the column names as follows:

```
public function approve($id)
{
    $vendor = DB::selectOne('select pic_email, roc_no from vendors where id = :id', compact('id'));

    Mail::to($vendor->pic_email)->send(new WelcomeMail($vendor->roc_no));

    return redirect('/account/pending')->with('success', 'Account approved!');
}
```

Comment: I got another error, `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`. Is it because the to() method do not accept arrays?

Comment: @AzwanAbdullah my mistake, the returned value is an instance of `stdClass`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

No need of two different queries you can finish this in one query

```
$user = DB::selectOne('select roc_no,pic_email from vendors where id = :id', ['id' => $id]);
OR
$user = DB::table('vendors')->where('id',$id)->select('roc_no','pic_email')->first();
// $user->pic_email; email 
// $user->roc_no;  ROC NO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a **TESTE IF you NEED it**! Through tinker as the following code.

Do the teste and it gonna give you if contain some error.

```
# SSH into droplet
# go to project
$ php artisan tinker
$ Mail::send('errors.401', [], function ($message) { $message->to('emmanuelbarturen@gmail.com')->subject('this works!'); });
# check your mailbox
```